# Interpolating values of a vector with Gaussian Process / Kriging in Python

Tags: python, gis, kriging

I'm attempting to interpolate wind speed and direction values on a map given some lat/long coordinates and then compare those values to my observed values. A couple papers suggest that Gaussian Process / Kriging are effective methods for this, but I don't understand the maths well enough to implement their models directly.

My dataframe looks something like:

```
lons_   lats_   U2M_    V2M_
.
.
.
```

I can follow the examples on SciPy, but am unsure if I can use their methods since I am attempting to interpolate vectors - wind speed and direction have both u & v components:

```
 ws_   = np.sqrt((U2M_ ** 2) + (V2M_ ** 2))
 dir_  = np.arctan2(V2M_,U2M_)
```

Where U2M_.... are just pd.Series(...) of the respective row-wise u,v components. Could I perform the calculation on each component separately, and then reconstruct the speed and direction values from the interpolated u,v values? I guess my questions is, is this a mathematically sound process?

Answer (score 0):

Wind speed can be interpolated directly from observations, but wind direction is more complicated. The standard approach is to convert into vectors - you're half-way towards this having computed the `u` and `v` components. You can average and interpolate these two values, before converting back into your `ws` and `dir` variables using the formulae you've given. The background to this is explained far better than I can in this really helpful resource:

Grange, Stuart. (2014). Technical note: Averaging wind speeds and directions. 10.13140/RG.2.1.3349.2006.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262766424_Technical_note_Averaging_wind_speeds_and_directions